# Most Effective Method to Deal With HTML Forms

Tags: html, c, database, forms, cgi

I've only recently gotten into web development, and I first started learning programming with C.

I now know some Java, JavaScript, and am in the process of learning jQuery; I've also planned to start learning PHP eventually.

But since I do like C, I'm going to ask 2 questions;

The first: What is the missing link between between the webpage and the compiled exe/cgi file that *fgets* and *fputs* the input? What am I not getting?

The second: What is the most efficient way (That is not C) to parse, and print HTML form data to a file?

This is my webpage's HTML:

```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
h1,h2,h3 {color:black;}
body {text-align:left;
background-image:url("");
    background-image: url("4.jpg");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;}

</style>
<title>
</title>

<link rel="FaviconIcon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">



</head>
<body>

<form>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<center>

<form action="c:/Apache24/cgi-bin/btform.cgi/"
method="post">
<h1>Name:<br>
<input type="text" Fullname="Fullname"><br>
Company/Organization<br>
<input type="text"
```

Organization="Organization">
Comment:

>

I was not able to post the program code for the C program because Stack Overflow kept throwing an error about code not being properly formatted, but the program compiles and accepts input from stdin (And prints to file) fine.

I basically want to use the C program I've compiled to take the input from the HTML form and print it into a text file.

Do let me know if this is missing anything or is not specific enough. I apologize, as this is my first post here.

Comment: *"What is the most efficient way..."* Define **efficient**. Also don't ask multiple questions in one question, especially as they are not related to each other.

Comment: Maybe the reason why SO is objecting to your C code is your badly formatted HTML? Part of it isn't quoted properly

Answer (score 0):

C is a very low level language, and whilst it is possible to do what you wish with C, there are much better suited languages which will handle all the boilerplate stuff.  ASP.NET for example will automatically populate a class object from form input.